# Split and count overlapping features within a layer

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, polygon

I would like to split a shapefile in qgis according to how the polygons overlaps.

See pic for explanation:

[image]

Comment: So..did it work?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a method.
It s a **grass** function included inside the **sextante** plugin.
See the screenshot.
I did a test with a shapefile that looked like yours.[image: pic]

**More Details:**

1. It is best to install QGIS Sextante Plugin. So you do not have to
   worry about importing/exporting to grass datasets.
2. The tool is   Located in `Sextante toolbox > Grass Commands > Vector > v.overlay`
3. Just open the tool and use the default parameters and you get the
   results in a new layer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am more familiar with ArcGIS than QGIS but I just did a brief search and think this would work:

1) Use the Union tool (as suggested by Darren Cope) to create your 7 features.
2) Under Data Management Tools use "Join attributes by location" and take the sum of the number of your original (purple in your map) polygons that overlap your new 7 features.

Thus where there is only 1 original poly, the new field = 1, where there are 2 polys, field = 2 and so on.

Comment: Here is a good site with info on the QGIS equivalent of a Spatial Join: http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php

Answer (score 0):

The standard QGIS Georeferencing tool "Union" will give the same result.

Comment: i can't get it working as per the asker's requirement..i gave input and union layers the same..are you sure it would work?